# How to fetch an array data from API and map it to the dart object?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) to map an array data (comes from API) to the dart object. The documentation uses a single Json object, not an array. I have the following codes:

**Json data:**

```
[
    {
        "channelId" :   1
        "channelTitle"  :   "Photos"
        "channelImage"  :   pr01.jpg
        "channelLastPost"   :   null
        "lastUpdate"    :   null
        "userRef"   :   1
    },
    {
        "channelId" :   2
        "channelTitle"  :   "Science"
        "channelImage"  :   pr02.jpg
        "channelLastPost"   :   "For test ...."
        "lastUpdate"    :   "2023-01-03"
        "userRef"   :   1
    }

]
```

**ChannelListModel.dart:**

```
class ChannelListModel {
  String creator;
  String? image;
  String title;
  String lastPost;
  String lastUpdate;

  ChannelListModel(
      {required this.creator,
      required this.image,
      required this.title,
      required this.lastPost,
      required this.lastUpdate});

  factory ChannelListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ChannelListModel(
        creator: json['userRef'],
        image: json['channelImage'],
        title: json['channelTitle'],
        lastPost: json['channelLastPost'],
        lastUpdate: json['lastUpdate']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "userRef" : creator,
      "channelImage" : image,
      "channelTitle" : title,
      "channelLastPost" : lastPost,
      "lastUpdate" : lastUpdate
    };
  }
}
```

**HttpRequest.dart:**

```
class HttpServices {
  Future<List<ChannelListModel>> getChannelList() async {
    var url = base.BaseURL.channelListUrl;
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return List<ChannelListModel>.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); //I have problem in this line
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

**ChannelPage.dart:**

```
class _ChannelsState extends State<Channels> {

  List<ChannelListModel> channels = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channels  = getChannelsFromHttp(); // A valid array object needs to be provided here.
  }

  getChannelsFromHttp()async{
    var httpService = HttpServices();
    var result = await httpService.getChannelList();
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: channels.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            ChannelCard(channelModel: channels[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to classify my codes so I decided to provided different dart files for each part. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Reminds me a bit of swift when you try to do that: `List<hannelListModel>.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));` where elements conform to Codable, so that they can automatically get decoded. 
Anyway the code in ChannelList is correct (yet it should be renamed `Channel`). 
you should cast the result of `jsonDecode(response.body)` as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>> data`. 
below that, you make a for loop, `for ( Map<String, dynamic> chunk in data)` and there you can decode each chunk individually with this `ChannelListModel.fromJson` method of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`returnList<ChannelListModel>.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));`

Try this code,

```
List<ChannelListModel> channels = [];
final res = jsonDecode(response.body);
channels.addAll(List<ChannelListModel>.from(
  (res).map((x) => ChannelListModel.fromJson(x))));
return channels;
```

Added based on comments

---

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getChannelsFromHttp();
  }

  getChannelsFromHttp()async{
    var httpService = HttpServices();
    var result = await httpService.getChannelList();
    setState((){
     channels = result;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tested your solution. In `ChannelPage.dart`, When I use `channels = getChannelsFromHttp()` the emulator screen gets red and says: `The Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<ChannelListModel>` . How can I fix it?

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fromJson` factory returns single `ChannelListModel`.
You can't use `List<ChannelListModel>.fromJson`. Instead iterate through `List` and convert each `json` to `ChannelListModel`

```
class HttpServices {
  Future<List<ChannelListModel>> getChannelList() async {
    var url = base.BaseURL.channelListUrl;
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      //return List<ChannelListModel>.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      return data.map((e) => ChannelListModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the **ChannelListModel.fromJson** method to handle a list of JSON objects instead of a single object. Here's one way to do it:

```
factory ChannelListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    return jsonList.map((json) => ChannelListModel(
        creator: json['userRef'],
        image: json['channelImage'],
        title: json['channelTitle'],
        lastPost: json['channelLastPost'],
        lastUpdate: json['lastUpdate'])
    ).toList();
  }
```

You can also use **jsonDecode** to convert the response body to a List and then use the above method to convert the list to **ChannelListModel**

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return ChannelListModel.fromJson(jsonData);
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
```

Also, you need to update the **getChannelsFromHttp** function to assign the result of **httpService.getChannelList()** to channels variable instead of calling the function again.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getChannelsFromHttp();
  }

  getChannelsFromHttp() async {
    var httpService = HttpServices();
    channels = await httpService.getChannelList();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

This should solve the problem in your code.